# RecyclerView item long press handling

Tags: android

How can I can handle long press event on items of recyclerview??
I want to generate an option menu on long press event on an item of recyclerview.

Comment: Activity.registerForContextMenu(View view) or View.setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View.OnLongClickListener)

Comment: Oh! how did I miss that. Thanks, that worked for me.